# Set a large amount of column in Terminal

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and the default Terminal.

I want to display result of database request with a lot of column, but cause the number of displayed column is insufficient the result is ugly ...

I want to set like 1000 or more displayed column in the terminal.

Comment: I don't think if `1000` is possible in the terminal but you will need to expand your terminal to accommodate them. The most I see is `256` from terminal settings

Comment: Yes, obviously but 256 is really insufficient :'(

Comment: "I want to display result of database request with a lot of column" That's why you can export to CSV and then use Calc to open the export. Or install workbench on the desktop.

Comment: For me 511x511 is the maximum I can specify in `gnome-terminal`'s profile preferences for the _initial_ size of the window, but it can be further enlarged manually. There's no such upper limit. However, do you really have such a large monitor that could accomodate so many cells in a readable way? I recommend you to use `less` or a similar pager, or as per the previous comment, use a dedicated app.

Comment: Are you asking about the number of data columns in the database, or the number of character columns in the terminal emulator?

Comment: You should check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924729/mysql-select-many-fields-how-best-to-display-in-terminal

Answer (score 1):

It's simple! The `bash` `COLUMNS` variable does the trick (see `man bash`).

For a single command:

```
env COLUMNS=2000 mycommand
```

For every command, until you change it or logout:

```
export COLUMNS=2000
```

Comment: Yes It could be nice but that don't work in MySql shell or cqlsh for exemple.

Comment: Even when started with `env COLUMNS=2000 cqlsh`? File a bug against MySql shell or `cqlsh`. Check with `strings $(type -p cqlsh) | grep COLUMNS`. This takes advantage of the fact that environment variables are accessed by name, so if `cqlsh` respects the `COLUMNS` environment variable, `cqlsh` will have the string "`COLUMNS`" in its binary. Also the original question didn't mention "MySql shell or cqlsh ". I answered in terms of character columns on a gnome-terminal.